# increase space for existing home directories

Tags: server, partitioning

I'm running ubuntu server Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.  When I originally installed my operating system I set up home directory and user accounts on a particular hard drive nvme1n1.  Recently I installed, partitioned, and mounted two new ssd drives sda and nvme0.  I added the new ssd drives because I was running out of space on my old hard drive.  I would like to share the space in the new drives across my user home accounts.  Is there a way to do this without having to wipe out my existing user accounts home directories?

I was reading online about volume groups, but it seems like those need to be created before you create home directories, in order to increase space using volume groups in the home directories.  Is that correct?

Is it possible to just move my home directories and all their data and programs (python, spark...) to one of the new ssd drives?  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

output:

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.7M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme1n1p2  228G  216G  299M 100% /
tmpfs            16G   12K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/nvme1n1p1  511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop2       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/sda1       916G   77M  870G   1% /mnt/data/sda
/dev/nvme0n1    916G   77M  870G   1% /mnt/data/nvme0n1
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed raid setups would allow to seamlessly treat different drives as if it were a single volume, but that cannot be implemented without erasing the current data.

Otherwise, it is indeed easy enough to just selectively move some of the user's home folders to new drives, and replace the original data by a symbolic link pointing to the moved data.

You need to copy the user's files preserving all file attributes. This can be done with `rsync` with the `-aH` (archive) option. You need the -H option only if the user's data contains hard links to files (i.e., files having the same inode, i.e, pointing to the same data) that exist under the folder structure that is being copied. That option recreates hard links in the destination, but requires significantly more time. Without that option, hardlinks will be copied as independent files (having a different inode) on the destination.

After you verified that the copy is successful, you may delete the original data and place a symbolic link with the same name that points to the new location. The user will not be aware of this change (unless, perhaps, the new drives are slower or faster).